# VueJS + Quasar Framework + Google Places Autocomplete = InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: vuejs3, google-places-api, quasar-framework, quasar, google-places-autocomplete

trying to implement the google autocomplete to my address form. I'm using the Quasar framework, can't find the sulution for: InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Below my address form and all scripts relevent:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_TOKEN&libraries=places"></script>
```

```
<template>
  <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
    <q-form @submit="save" class="q-gutter-md">
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.title"
        :label="$t('address_title_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_title_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty]"
      />
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.country"
        :label="$t('address_country_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_country_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty]"
      />
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.city"
        :label="$t('address_city_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_city_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty, isCityOrPostalCode]"
      />
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.code"
        :label="$t('address_code_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_code_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty]"
      />
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.street"
        ref="streetRef"
        id="streetRef"
        :label="$t('address_street_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_street_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty]"
      />
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="modelAddress.number"
        :label="$t('address_number_label')"
        :hint="$t('address_number_hint')"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[isNotEmpty]"
      />
      <div class="address-form-btn">
        <q-btn color="primary" :label="$t('save_btn')" type="submit" />
      </div>
    </q-form>
  </q-card-section>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "AddressFrom",
  setup () {
    const streetRef = ref()
    onMounted(() => {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(streetRef.value, {
        types: ['address'], 
        fields: ['address_components']
      })
    })
    return { streetRef }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modelAddress: this.address
    }
  },
  props: {
    address: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.$emit("save", this.$data.modelAddress)
    },
    isNotEmpty(val) {
      if (!val) {
        return this.$t("please_pick_something")
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Hope this question is generic so also others can benefit

Comment: My best guess is that the ref `streetRef` is returning a `<div>` element instead of an `<input>` of type text. Can you make sure? In that case the error makes sense. Google only supports `type="text"` hence the error `...not an instance of HTMLInputElement`

Comment: @Fanoflix It seems that you pointed me on the right track, as when I Changed the q-input to input the API seems to start broadcast to google API. But at the same time I want to use the quasar component. So do u know a way to make it work?

Comment: Try changing the streetRef from `ref()` to `ref(null)`. I dont know if that will fix it. But attaching a ref to a quasar component should bind it to the relevant element instead of the wrapper. Can you set up a codesandbox with Quasar (without the google API) so I can test it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if my solution is the most elegant, but it's working:

so below quasar input setup:

```
<q-input
 v-model="modelAddress.street"
 ref="streetRef"
 @keypress="autocompleteLocation"
/>
```

And needed methods:

```
setup () {
 return { 
  streetRef: ref()
 }
},
methods: {
 autocompleteLocation () {
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.streetRef.getNativeElement(), {
   types: ['address'], 
   fields: ['address_components']
  })
 }
}
```

Also after the API was returning queries it was not visible I needed to add below class style to return new google component which show up with the response:

```
<style scope>
.pac-container {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
</style>
```

If you have similar problems, you can also see this quasar form post for additional inspiration: https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/7541/google-places-autocomplete-using-q-input-not-working-but-works-with-input

Hope this helps.